# how to get location tokens to work in pathauto

Tags: tokens, location

I am attempting to use a city location in the URL via pathauto. I have this for the URL [node:title]/[node:location:city:0]

When I create a new node, however, only the title is inserted into the URL.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that token [node:location:city:?] is from location_node module, not from cck field. Did you created your own field with location in your node? In this case you have to enable location_entity module and using [node:field_mylocation:city:?] token.

Comment: I have tried using this token ([node:title]/[node:field_my_location:city:0]) but I always get the following error message when trying to save the setting: "Pattern for all test type paths is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field_my_location:city:0]".

I even created a new test content type with the location field labeled "my location".

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using the field from the location_node module. When I attempt to use a (location) field I add to the content type, I cannot use a token. I get the invalid token error message when I attempt to use a token for an added location field.

Comment: Have you got enable location_entity module??

Comment: I did enable the location_entity module. I still go the error message when attempting to add a token to a location field that I had added to the content type.